# How to remove error 500 while using api to get data

Tags: python, keyword-search

Below is the code where I am using yake api to extract keywords, in this I am passing the url in the api and using to get the json objectg but getting error 500 pleasee check, below is the snippet of the code

```
try:
    response = requests.get(f'http://yake.inesctec.pt/yake/v2/extract_keywords?content={url}&max_ngram_size=3&number_of_keywords=20&highlight=true',
                            params = {"format":"json"})
        # print(response)
    print(response.json())
except ConnectionError as err: #i am getting error in this line 
   time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: What is `url` value which cause malfunction?

Comment: check the input ```url```. I have tried by putting google.com and it working fine. or provide your ```url``` here.